# Retrieving big size images for links from stream table

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

We have the need to displaying hi-res images on iOS devices for the links shared in the wall from users friends.
For that we make a SELECT to the stream table including the field 'attachment' in the request.
From the 'attachment' array we get the 'media' dictionary.
After that, from the 'media' dictionary, src key give us the value of the thumbnail.

For links, the image size provided by src is normally small and it is difficult to offer a good presentation of the data in that size.

My question is:

Is there any other way to retrieve big size images of the links shared in the wall by friends?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just retrieve the post’s info from the Graph API, there’s a field `picture` in it, containing a link like this,

> https;//fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDkuCdvs9FkPGT_&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.faz.net\u00252Fpolopoly_fs\u00252F1.1809933.1341414925\u002521\u00252Fimage\u00252F2222140031.jpg_gen\u00252Fderivatives\u00252Farticle_top_teaser\u00252F2222140031.jpg

Should be easy to extract the original image URL from that – and then you can try and grab that, in the hope that it’s a bigger version.